# Spring adding data to database, BindingResult result hasErrors

Tags: java, spring

Im trying to add an Agent to my database, it detects that the result has errors so doesn't add to the database, i suspect it is because BindingResult isn't working.

Code for the form:

```
 <form:form method="POST" action="/AgentsCRUD/agent/addAgent" modelAttribute="agent">
    <table>
     <tr> 
       <td><form:label path="agentId"><spring:message code="label.agentId" /></form:label></td>
       <td><form:input path="agentId"/></td> 
       <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="agentId"/> </td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
       <td><form:label path="name"><spring:message code="label.name" /></form:label></td>
       <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
       <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="name"/> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><form:label path="phone"><spring:message code="label.phone" /></form:label></td>
       <td><form:input path="phone"/></td>
       <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="phone"/> </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><form:label path="fax"><spring:message code="label.fax" /></form:label></td>
     <td><form:input path="fax"/></td>
     <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="fax"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><form:label path="email"><spring:message code="label.email" /></form:label></td>
      <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
      <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="email"/> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <spring:message code="submit.button" var="labelSubmit"></spring:message>
       <td><input type="submit" value="${labelSubmit}"/></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Code in the controller is:

```
@PostMapping("/addAgent")
public ModelAndView addAnAgent(ModelMap model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("agent") Agents agent, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("/addAgent");
    }
    service.addAnAgent(agent);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/agent");
}
```

Code for the service is:

```
   public void addAnAgent(Agents agent) {
     EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();
     EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();  
     try {
       trans.begin();
       em.persist(agent);
       trans.commit();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex);
     } finally {
         em.close();
     }
   }
```

Comment: So what are the errors?

Comment: Rather than showing us `addAnAgent()`, which you say isn't being called, how about you show us `Agents`? Might be more useful to us.

Comment: @Andreas it doesnt show any errors, it just redirects me to the /addAgent action, i tried to use the debugger and it doesn't tell me anything, all the values are showing full. i admit it was pointless showing addAnAgent() because it isnt going into to, i just wasnt thinking, i will create a new question and delete this one with the additional class

Comment: Why not just **edit** this question and replace `addAnAgent()` with `Agents`?

Answer (score 0):

found out that i had extra tables in the database i wasn't aware of, taking in these values in the jsp fixed it

```
             <tr>
                <td><form:label path="username"><spring:message code="label.username" /></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="username"/></td>
                <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="username"/> </td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><form:label path="password"><spring:message code="label.password" /></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="password"/></td>
                <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="password"/> </td>
            </tr>
```